# How could VS code recognize linux code on windows OS?

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio-code

My university project asked me to deal with some problem regard socket programming.

However, my machine is windows OS, and provided code is Linux thing. I do have a VM that is offered by

university, but I think this would only be helpful when I try to compile my finished code.

Current problem is, VS code does not resolve <netdb.h> and some relative

commands, hence it stucks here and any code below this header file is not

going to be detected if any error has been made.

I really need help on this.

Comment: Did you consider installing [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com/) or [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your personal laptop? What will happen to you if you did? For students learning programming, it is an excellent OS. And it is [open source](https://opensource.com/resources/what-open-source)

Comment: Look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview

Comment: I have downloaded ubuntu, how do I include linux header files in VS code?

Comment: Are you *running* Ubuntu? And header files are relevant to the *compiler* (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) but as far as I know VSCode is a source code editor. My recommendation is to read the [documentation of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/index.html) and [the documentation of VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/) and [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

Comment: maybe you can use cygwin

Answer (score 1):

Try using VMware or VirtualBox and look up a tutorial on how to setup linux on it. It'll just make a kinda os thingy and it'll be a os in a os. Use this ubuntu iso: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Linux kernel as a subsystem, after this you can run Linux code on wsl/bash terminal on windows and also compile C/C++ code with the subsystem, for introductions see in:
https://ubuntu.com/wsl